# When specifying an isolation level how long does it last for?

Tags: parallel-processing, database, isolation-level

Does an isolation level still apply until a different one is specified or does it only apply to the next transaction?

For example:

```
SET TRANSACTION READ WRITE
 ISOLTATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
 SELECT foo FROM aTable;
 SELECT bar FROM aTable;
```

When reading the column `bar` is the isolation level back to the default serializable?

To make sure I'm not confused, when specifying the isolation level it is dbms wide right?

Comment: It's for the Session lifetime

Comment: @Chandu is session lifetime for as long as the user/program is connected to the database?

Comment: Session life time is completely controlled by the component that is creating/handling the session. Basically either when a transaction is started to when it is committed or when a connection isopened till its closed for implicit transactions